# issue with centering div that's right aligned to parent in react native

Tags: html, css, react-native

I'm having such a hard time transferring something I wrote in HTML/CSS into React Native. The basic idea is that I'm trying to align some divs to the right of a parent div that's as small as possible. Then, I'm trying to center that parent div on the page.

The html looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .outer {
      background-color: gray;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .container {
      background-color: pink;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .column {
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: purple;
      padding: 5%;
    }
    
    .row {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    
    p h3 {
      align-self: flex-start;
    }
    
    .right {
      color: red;
      min-width: 20%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column left">
          <p>test name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column right">
          <h2>Yes</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="column left">
          <p>long long long name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column right">
          <h2>No</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="column left">
          <p>short</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column right">
          <h2>No</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

But when I transfer this into React Native code, it doesn't look the same! The pink container is no longer centered, and you cannot view the gray outer div (copy paste this into Snack to see what I mean):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

let Test = () => (
    <View style={styles_alt.outer}>
      <View style={styles_alt.container}>
        <View style={styles_alt.row}>
          <View style={{...styles_alt.column, ...styles_alt.left}}>
            <Text>test name</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{...styles_alt.column, ...styles_alt.right}}>
            <Text>Yes</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
  
        <View style={styles_alt.row}>
          <View style={{...styles_alt.column, ...styles_alt.left}}>
            <Text>long long long name</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{...styles_alt.column, ...styles_alt.right}}>
            <Text>No</Text>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={styles_alt.row}>
          <View style={{...styles_alt.column, ...styles_alt.left}}>
            <Text>name</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{...styles_alt.column, ...styles_alt.right}}>
            <Text>Yes</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
  
      </View>
    </View>
  );

const styles_alt = {
  outer: {
    backgroundColor: "gray",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },

  container: {
    backgroundColor: "pink",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
  }, 

  column: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    backgroundColor: "purple",
    padding: "5%",

  },
  
  row: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",


  },

  p: {
    alignSelf: "flex-start",
  },

  h3: {
    alignSelf: "flex-start",
  },

  right: {
    color: "red",
    minWidth: "20%",
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{marginTop: "30%"}}>
        <Test/ >
    </View>
  );
}
```

If anyone is willing to help me out I'd appreciate it a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Currently working on a [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-sea-p2569) and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/013xo5qL/)

This biggest issue I see is applying View Styles to Text Components. For example:

```
    <View style={{...styles_alt.column, ...styles_alt.right}}>
            <Text>No</Text>
    </View>
```

should be:

```
    <View style={styles_alt.column}>
            <Text style={styles_alt.right}>No</Text>
    </View>
```

You have mismatched html elements as well:

```
  <p>short</a>
```

```
 <p>long long long name</a>
```

Also, please keep in mind that html elements such as h2 have [default stylings](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp) that need to be added manually to your react native styling.

Comment: thank you for pointing these issues out. However, what I'm really having trouble with is centering the `container` within `outer`. I updated my post to make this clearer